# Matlab: Sort a cell array with respect to their hierarchy

Tags: matlab, sorting, cell-array

I want to sort a table of cell arrays (Nx2) with respect to the hierarchy written in the first column of the cell array.

For example:

```
MdlTbl={'1','VW';
'1.1', 'Golf';
'1.2', 'Passat';
'1.3', 'Polo';
'2','Mercedes';
'2.1', 'A-Klasse';
'2.1.1', 'Grün';
'2.1.2', 'Rosa';
'2.1.3', 'gelb';
'2.2', 'B-Klasse';
'2.3', 'e-Klasse';
'2.4', 'G-Klasse';
'3','Audi';
'3.1', 'A1';
'3.1.1', 'Schwarz';
'3.1.2', 'Karriert';
'3.2', 'A2';};
```

for a alphabetical order the result should look like:

```
SortModel = 

'1'        'Audi'    
'1.1'      'A1'      
'1.1.1'    'Karriert'
'1.1.2'    'Schwarz' 
'1.2'      'A2'      
'2'        'Mercedes'
'2.1'      'A-Klasse'
'2.1.1'    'gelb'    
'2.1.2'    'Grün'    
'2.1.3'    'Rosa'    
'2.2'      'B-Klasse'
'2.3'      'e-Klasse'
'2.4'      'G-Klasse'
'3'        'VW'
'3.1'      'Golf'    
'3.2'      'Passat'  
'3.3'      'Polo'
```

The way of sorting (e.g alphabetically) doesn't really matter. It's just for uniform different tables to compare them with each other afterwards. 
The depth of the hierarchy as well as the length of the table may differ. The names in column 2 may be appear twice e.g 'Golf', 'Golf'.

I wrote a quite complex script which is working for this easy example, but not for bigger tables. Now I am wondering if there is an easy way with one of the thousand matlab functions?

Thank you!

Comment: It's kind of confusing, that your second table contains different entries than the first "unsorted" one - e.g. `1.1.1`, `3.1.1` and others. I assume that's not by intention?

Comment: No that's exactly the intention of the sorting. I try to describe it more clearly: Imagine a top layer, which includes 3 Sublayers: Audi, VW, Mercedes. These sublayers include other sublayers like A1,A2 etc. It's a parent/children relationship. Now I want to sort the diffrent layers, and of course the index of the sublayers have to change accordingly. I hope it helps to understand the problem

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'm getting the problem right - but [`sortrows`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) does pretty much what you're looking for:

```
>> sortrows(MdlTbl)

ans = 

    '1'        'VW'      
    '1.1'      'Golf'    
    '1.2'      'Passat'  
    '1.3'      'Polo'    
    '2'        'Mercedes'
    '2.1'      'A-Klasse'
    '2.1.1'    'Grün'    
    '2.1.2'    'Rosa'    
    '2.1.3'    'gelb'    
    '2.2'      'B-Klasse'
    '2.3'      'e-Klasse'
    '2.4'      'G-Klasse'
    '3'        'Audi'    
    '3.1'      'A1'      
    '3.1.1'    'Schwarz' 
    '3.1.2'    'Karriert'
    '3.2'      'A2'
```

Comment: I've answered your first question. This answer is just giving me the original table back, because it's sorting the first row, which is already in Order.